# Standard deviation for a huge numpy array without copy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 5-D numpy array that I want to calculate the standard deviation for the last axis. The array is a memory mapped numpy array(70GB, shape=(220*240*240*150*5)).

```
np.std(data,axis=4)
```

Obviously, it gives me memory error. Is there a way to find the standard variation without copying operation?